# I want to send data from my React application to python

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, axios

I have a React Application with backend on Nodejs and database MySQL, I am using a python api and I want to send data from my React input fields to python so that I can use that data as parameters to my python functions. For this, I am using axios to send data to a flask server, but I am getting this cyclic object error. I have attached the code below.

React Component :

```
    const send_data = ()=>
    {
        const trade = document.getElementById("trade");
        const index = document.getElementById("index");
        const tradeType = document.getElementById("type");
        const strikePrice = document.getElementById("strikeP");
        const trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");
        const perc = document.getElementById("percentage");
        const ce = document.getElementById("ce");
        const pe = document.getElementById("pe");
        const entry = document.getElementById("entry");
        const exit = document.getElementById("exit");
    
    
        axios.post("127.0.0.1:5000/trade_data" , {
            trade_no : trade.value,
            index_name : index.value,
            trade_type : tradeType.value,
            strike_price : strikePrice,
            ce_d : ce.value,
            pe_d : pe.value,
            entry_time : entry.value,
            exit_time : exit.value,
            trigger_points : trigger.value,
            sl_percentage : perc.value
        }).then(console.log("Data Sent"));
    }
```

and I am calling this function onclicking the button :

```
   <button id="start" onClick={send_data}>Start</button>
```

Here is my flask code:

```
from flask import Flask
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/trade_data' , methods = ['GET'])

def show_data():
    r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/trade_data")
    print(r)
    return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

And here is the error I am getting :
[image]

New error :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you pass strikePrice as an object instead of value field and JSON.stringify() doesn't support object references. Try this:

```
 axios.post("127.0.0.1:5000/trade_data" , {
        trade_no : trade.value,
        index_name : index.value,
        trade_type : tradeType.value,
        strike_price : strikePrice.value,
        ce_d : ce.value,
        pe_d : pe.value,
        entry_time : entry.value,
        exit_time : exit.value,
        trigger_points : trigger.value,
        sl_percentage : perc.value
    }).then(console.log("Data Sent"));
```

You can read more information about error [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value#what_went_wrong)

Comment: I fixed this but now I am getting the error attached below:

Comment: I edited my question you can see the error below

Comment: CORS is a common error to see in local applications. If you need more information, you can read official documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors).

However, it will probably help you this library on flask server side https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score -1):

Stringify JSON Object and then try sending it. maybe works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).